# Storing objects into NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to build a sample app that grabs some json from a url and display it in a table view. I'm having an issue storing the data into an object and inserting these objects into an NSMutableArray.

TableView.m

```
- (void) getDataFromAPI {
    NSString *endpoint = @"http://www.somesite.com/list.php";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:endpoint];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        [self createMovies: JSON];
    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response , NSError *error , id JSON){
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Uh oh, there's been a problem!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Retry", nil];
        [alert show];
    }];
    [operation start];
}

- (void) createMovies: (id) json {

    NSMutableArray *list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (id entry in json) {
        Movie *aMovie = [[Movie alloc] init];
        aMovie.movieId = [entry objectForKey:@"id"];
        aMovie.title = [entry objectForKey:@"title"];
        aMovie.director = [entry objectForKey:@"director"];
        aMovie.price = [entry objectForKey:@"price"];

        aMovie = nil;
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", list);
    self.movieList = list;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.movieList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self getDataFromAPI];
    self.title = @"Movies";


    NSLog(@"%@", self.movieList);
}
```

When I try to inspect the `self.movieList` in `viewDidLoad` it has zero objects, but when I inspect the `list` in  `createMovies` I get six objects.

An example of my json data:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Transformers",
    "price": 29.54,
    "Director": "Michael Bay"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "South Park",
    "price": 34.88,
    "author": "Matt Stone, Trey Parker"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "The Hobbit",
    "price": 20.04,
    "author": "Peter Jackson"
  }
]
```

Comment: Well, your request is asynchronous...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AFJSONRequestOperation` is asynchronously loading the data.   So, when the [incorrectly named -- should just be `loadDataFromAPI`] `getDataFromAPI` method has returned, the data hasn't yet actually been loaded.

Your `createMovies:` method should trigger a UI refresh that causes the movies to be displayed.

Comment: I haven't even got to the point of sticking it into the UI yet so a UI refresh won't help I don't think.

Comment: Same problem, though.   You are asynchronously loading something and printing out the results before it is loaded.

Comment: But in the AFJSONRequestionOperation i call createMovies in the success method, does that not mean that the request has finished loading asynchronously?

Comment: @creminsn Yes, you call `createMovies` once the data is finished loading asynchronously. As stated, the problem is in `viewDidLoad`. When you log the movies in `viewDidLoad`, the data hasn't loaded yet since it is in progress in the background.

Comment: @rmaddy how can I check to see if the async request has completed and then log it in viewDidLoad()?

Comment: @creminsn You don't. `viewDidLoad` shouldn't care when it's done. `viewDidLoad` simply kicks off the loading. Your `createMovies` deals with the completion. If you need to reload a table view then do so at the end of `createMovies`. But make sure you call `reloadData` on the main thread. Your `createMovies` may be called on a background thread (see the docs as needed).